# JavaScript: window.confirm with two window locations?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm creating a HTML IOS App with a Log in System.

At the moment when the user presses "log out" It will vibrate and a confirmation will pop up to say "are you sure you want to log out" there are two answers... Ok and Cancel.

I want OK to go to index.html
but CANCEL to stay on the same page (not log out).

At the moment both Ok and Cancel are directing to index.html (see code)

```
   function vibrate() {
        navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);
        window.confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?')
        window.location.href='index.html';
    }
```

I'd appreciate some help

Thanks

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,  minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
        }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {

        }

function vibrate() { 
navigator.notification.vibrate(2000); 
navigator.notification.confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?',
     decide,
     'confirm logout?',
     ['cancel','ok'],
      );
        }
        function decide(button){
      if(button==2){
    window.location.href='index.html'; 
      }else{
         //Another stuff
      }     
  }

              </script>

          <title>Logged in</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Welcome</h1>

  <p><a href="2index.html">Home</a></p>
  <p><a href="2courses.html">Courses</a></p>


  <input type="button" value="Log Out"onClick="vibrate();">
     </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With phonegap you should do something like this

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,  minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>



  <script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

}

function vibrate() { 
navigator.notification.vibrate(2000); 
navigator.notification.confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?',
     decide,
     'confirm logout?',
     ['cancel','ok']
      );
}


function decide(button){
      if(button==2){
        window.location.href='index.html'; 
      }else{
         //Another stuff
      }     
 }


              </script>

          <title>Logged in</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Welcome</h1>

  <p><a href="2index.html">Home</a></p>
  <p><a href="2courses.html">Courses</a></p>


  <input type="button" value="Log Out"onClick="vibrate();">
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. One more thing: for the log in button... should I still be using this <input type="button" value="Log Out"onClick="vibrate(); return false;"> or should I be calling the decide function button also? As its not working for me.

Comment: Still not working, should I not be calling the button function?

Comment: No u dont need to call decide function.. U r using phonegap right?

Comment: Yeh - Using Phonegap through Xcode - I dont know why its not working :(

Comment: Check with your Cordova js version

Comment: I am using Cordova.js yes